# left-justify textfield without resizing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textfield

I would like to set a fixed width for an input textfield with an embedded font.  I would like to have the option to left-, right-, or center-justify the text.  This is proving difficult.

If I set `myTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;`, I get left-justified text, but the textfield width changes with each keystroke.  Same trade-off with `TextFieldAutoSize.RIGHT` and `TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER`.

Now, if I use `TextFieldAutoSize.NONE`, then I can fix the width and height of my textfield, making it the size I want... but the cursor is always blinking in the middle of the textfield.  What's the secret to justifying that cursor to the left [or right] and the textfield staying the size I initially set it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [TextFormat classes align property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html#align) with the [TextFormatAlign class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormatAlign.html) for paragraph alignment. The TextField autoSize changed the bounding box size of the TextField.

So you would do something like:

```
myTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.NONE; // This is the default anyway.
var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myTextFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.LEFT;
myTextField.defaultTextFormat = myTextFormat;
```